# Blockchain explorer: Error: Cannot find module

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

While executing below command i am getting error:

Command:

```
node main.js
```

Error:

```
module.js:550
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/murugesan/Blockchain/fabric-explorer/app/query.js:21:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded from a previous version of fabric to 1.3, EventHub.js no longer exists. You have to change your code to use ChannelEventHub instead. See [How to use the channel-based event service](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-channel-events.html) for details.

If you are still using fabric 1.2 or earlier, you may have the wrong client version installed. To install the correct version, run

```
npm install fabric-ca-client@fabricVersion
```

e.g.

```
npm install fabric-ca-client@1.2.1
```